# What are the ways of applying force axially, without any contact, to a rotating object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, rotational-dynamics

Is there any other method except just using permanent magnets ? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using the various methods ?

[image: Rough Diagram]

Comment: do you have a diagram for what you mean by "axial" ?

Comment: @annav I have added a diagram

Comment: the magnetic field has to be axial, but the force generated is tangent . http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html . There is a cross product.

Comment: Is the part free floating (like in space), or attached to something?

Comment: I think this question has merit in a theoretical sense and should remain open.I mean the question about how to weight your head was very popular and highly rated and this one isn't that far off in concept here.

Comment: @ja72 The disc is attached to an axis to a rigid body. The disc is free to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Blowing pressurized air at the outer edge of the rotating object will get it to spin relatively fast, a static charge has a weak effect on another charged object. There could be more ways to do this but those are the easiest to use.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to mention that the force is to applied axially.

Comment: water turbines too are rotating due to the flow. Axially is a later edit

Comment: We used to accelerate bearings with compressed air - a **very** dangerous activity as the bearings can shatter...

Answer (score 0):

One can place a charge near the base of the cylinder, it will polarize and attract the cylinder (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics#Electrostatic_induction). One can also use radiation pressure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure).

Comment: How can you keep the charge on the disc for a long time ?

Comment: @DiyankoBhowmik : I don't quite understand your question. I did not offer to put a charge on the disk. I offered to place a charge near the disk, on the disk's axis.

Comment: Okay, but how can that be done ? I had thought that you wanted to put a charge on the disk in some way.

Comment: @DiyankoBhowmik : No, I did not write anywhere that the charge is put on the disk. I had the following picture in mind: a (small) charged object is placed near a base of the cylinder, at some distance from the base, on the axis of the cylinder. The charge will polarize the cylinder and will attract it. As the cylinder moves towards the charged object, one can move the latter away from the cylinder along the axis to prevent a contact between the charged object and the disk.